# PLINQ to Entity Framework: why shouldn't it be used?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6, plinq

I read somewhere that you shouldn't use PLINQ on Entity Framework or SQL. I can't remember where I read it or what the reasons were, but I did some experimentation. Using traditional LINQ to Entity Framework to load a database table that's expected to grow to be quite large currently takes 12 to 13 milliseconds. However, when I add .AsParallel() the same query runs in 2 to 4 milliseconds, and I get the same exact results.

So if I get the same results faster using PLINQ, what are the pitfalls of using PLINQ to Entity Framework?

Comment: Because it's pointless? The *server* executes the query. If you make multiple concurrent connections, you increase locks and contention. A *single* query that loads multiple items is faster than N concurrent ones. If your query is slow, check *why* - are you missing indexes? Is it too complex? What does the actual SQL look like?

Comment: The only thing I was doing, as I indicated, was load a table, a simple "from x in dbSet select x".

Comment: This *simple* operation is the most expensive thing you can do to a database - you ignore all indexing, buffering and acceleration mechanisms and load *all* data from disk at maximum speed and maximum IO. A database combine data, filter and transform results using far better algorithms than any client program. An in-memory dictionary is just a hash using a single core for searches. The server uses B-Trees, SSE2 commands and multiple cores instead with optimized buffering

Comment: If you *do* want to pull all data, eg as part of an ETL job that processes far more data that can fit in memory, you actually need to *disable* buffering - no need wasting RAM for data that won't be reused anyway.  Process the data as a stream, and send it to its target as soon as possible. You could process GBs of data using only a few MBs of RAM this way. If you do that, parallel processing makes sense, eg by creating a processing pipeline where each step runs in a different thread

Comment: Another option is to use partitioned data and use multiple connections to pull data from each partition in parallel. If the partitions are stored in different disks/arrays you'll be able to read from all of them at the same time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are some dangers, IE the the DbContext cannot be accessed by multiple threads simultaneously.  And often little upside, ie PLINQ will synchronize access to IEnumerable.MoveNext() which does all the work of reading the data, creating the Entities and interacting with the change tracker.

But if you do a lot of work with the returned entities, that does not touch the DbContext (ie no SaveChanges(), no Lazy Loading, etc), you can use PLINQ.

But most of the examples I can think of would be better-optimized by building the operation into the original query, or by performing server-side raw SQL.

So if you have a bunch of CPU-intensive domain logic you need to run across a collection of entities, you could operate across the results in parallel, but you might be better-off creating a separate DbContext *inside* the parallel execution block.